# tasklist command won't exit when RedirectStandardOutput is true

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, process

I'm trying to execute a command and wait for it to exit:

```
Process proc = new Process();

proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c tasklist";
proc.Start();

proc.WaitForExit();
return;
```

However, `tasklist` command never exit if `RedirectStandardOutput` is set to true.

If I set `RedirectStandardOutput` to false or change the command to `/c whoami`, it exit almost immediately.

Any ideas?

Comment: Insert `console.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());` between `proc.Start();` and `proc.WaitForExit();`

Comment: @JosefZ Adding ReadToEnd() worked. But I also need to limit the maximum bytes to read with `proc.StandardOutput.Read()`. If I call `Read()` before `WaitForExit()` I will get partial output; If I do `WaitForExit()` first it will stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the output before calling `WaitForExit()`, this sample works fine:

```cs
Process proc = new Process();

proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c tasklist";
proc.Start();

var output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
proc.WaitForExit();

Console.WriteLine(output);
return;
```

Without reading an output `tasklist` process waits until parent process read the output, according to remarks section of [`RedirectStandardOutput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

> A deadlock condition can result if the parent process calls
>   `p.WaitForExit` before `p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd` and the child process
>   writes enough text to fill the redirected stream. The parent process
>   would wait indefinitely for the child process to exit. The child
>   process would wait indefinitely for the parent to read from the full
>   `StandardOutput` stream.

You can also do an asynchronous reading of process output (and limit a process wait for exit timeout), like this

```cs
Process proc = new Process();
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c tasklist";
proc.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
{
    output.Append(e.Data).Append("\n");
};
proc.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) =>
{
    output.Append(e.Data).Append("\n");
};

proc.Start();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
proc.WaitForExit(100);

Console.WriteLine(output);

return;
```

Also, if you are going to redirect both streams (error and output), you have read at least one of them asynchronously, because of deadlocks again (MSDN link shows an example)